# Servo motor sweeps beyond 180

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I'm trying to get my servo motor to sweep from 0 to 180 degrees then back to 0 degrees for infinite amount of times. I using the following code but my motor keeps resetting when it get backs to 0 degrees (meaning it goes 0-->180-->0 then completes a 360 and starts over). Also the 0-180 degree sweep appears to be more of a 0-270 degree sweep. Anyone running into these problems?

```cpp
int angle = 0;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  myservo.write(angle);
}

void loop()
{
  for (angle = 0; angle < 180; angle += 1)
  {
    myservo.write(angle);
    delay (50);
  }

  for (angle = 180; angle > 0; angle -= 1)
  {
    myservo.write(angle);    
    delay(50);
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to have the servo sweep at a particular speed? Why not just use:

```
void loop()
{
  angle=180;
  myservo.write(angle);

  delay(500); //Allow 0.5 seconds for servo to complete it's move; adjust as necessary depending on servo's rotation speed.

  angle=0;
  myservo.write(angle);

  delay(500); //Allow 0.5 seconds for servo to complete it's move; adjust as necessary depending on servo's rotation speed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it worked for 0.5 second delay but when I increased the time the servo makes a 360 again. it goes 180 degrees-->360 turn-->0 degree--> 180 then pauses-->360 degree turn and repeats.

Comment: Can you post a link to the exact servo unit you are using?

Comment: I purchased the Elegoo Uno Project Super Starter Kit                                             (http://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-uno-project-super-starter-kit/)

Comment: If that servo goes over 180 travel, something is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

Is your servo the modified 360 degree type with no position feedback (meaning the internal feedback potentiometer has been disabled)?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I made no modifications to it.

Comment: Is it a continuous rotation servo ? Can you give the brand and type and a link to where you bought it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a bunch of SG90 mini servos so I tried your code. My servos turn 0 -> 180 -> 0 -> 180 -> 0 -> 180, over and over. No 360 spins at all.

- Maybe your servo is defect? (can you check with another servo?)
- Maybe it is not getting enough power? (how are you powering it?) It needs at least 4.8V and at least 220mA
- Maybe it doesn't get a strong clean PWM signal? (You'll probably need an oscilloscope to check this)